# How to build a condensed for-loop inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I encountered a really condensed chunk of code which uses a for-loop and an if statement to find all numbers inside a string, and add them to a list. The problem is that I do not understand why it works.

```
string = "h3110 23 cat 444.4 rabbit 11 2 dog"
alist = [int(s) for s in string.split() if s.isdigit()]
print (alist)
```

this prints `['23', '11', '2']`

There are two bits I do not get:

1. How is "s" in int(s) in line 2 being defined, even though it is entered before the for-loop?
2. Why does this code function without an else/return/pass/etc. argument inplace for the if statement?

This code basically does the following:

```
alist = []
for s in string.split():
    if s.isdigit():
        alist.append(s)
    else:
        pass
print (alist)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a "for loop inside a list." It's special syntax in Python called a "List Comprehension." The basic syntax is: `[<expression> for <var> in <iterable>]` or with an optional conditional: `[<expression> for <var> in <iterable> if <condition>]`. It basically translates to:

```
new_list = []
for <var> in <iterable>:
    if <condition>:
        new_list.append(<expression>)
```

It sounds like you understand it correctly, you were just unaware that this is special syntax, which is why it looks like it's trying to access a variable that is not yet declared or defined. If you are interested, you can find more information about how they work here: http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

Answer (score 0):

The one-liner does exactly what you have written below, except that `s` is converted to an integer (it should be `alist.append(int(s))`).

How does the one-liner work? It creates a new list of all the elements of an existing list (in your case the existing list is `string.split()`) for which the condition after `if` is true - that the element is indeed a digit.